# home/username directory chmod 750 best for security but are some errors

Tags: linux, security, chmod

in directory /home/username/public_html
I have a website with CMS.

When I change chmod of /home/username directory to 750, my site doesn't work. I believe my CMS have no access to it.

Is there any way to improve /home/username directory security by chmod, so the website in subdirectory still works well?

Comment: Do you have any interesting thing in the logs, the one of the CMs, or `/var/log/syslog` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need your website to be in `/home/$user/...`, then you could change the permission of your directory like this :
Create a group for this directory

```sh
groupadd home_user
```

add your user, and the user executing the CMS (e.g. wordpress) inside this group.

```sh
usermod -A -g $user  home_user
usermod -A -g wordpress  home_user
```

Then change the permission of your home folder:

```sh
chown $USER:home_user /home/$USER
chmod 770 /home/$USER # or 750 if it is enough
```

Then it should work.

---

BUT !

Having your website in the home folder, this is bad practice.
It would be better to have it under `/var/www/` or `/www/` or `/opt/www/`

Then it is easier to segregate. You give the authorisation to this folder ONLY to the user which is running the website. And he has no other permission.

Comment: Sometimes services save some config files under /home/user folder. When change chmod to 750 of the user dir, does it break something too?

Comment: Not that i know of. Who is gonna write to your home : The softare you may launch (they have your UID),  the system services (they are root). So I don't see any reason for that to not work

Comment: no service writes by default to any home folders. tell us more about this kind of story